# R - How to change the height of images when arranging in grids

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I want to arrange an image along side some plots. My example looks like this:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(RCurl)
library(png)

img0 <- readPNG(getURLContent('http://carpng.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb/red-cartoon-car-8056-0.png'))
grob0 <- rasterGrob(img0)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy))+ geom_point()+ geom_line()
p3 <- grid.arrange(p,p,p)

grid.arrange(grob0, p3, ncol=2)
```

Which looks like:
[image]

I want the car image height to match the height of the three plots.

Additionally in my actual data the plots have differing x axis lengths is there a way to plot them so the x axes are scaled relative to each other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(RCurl)
library(png)

img0 <- readPNG(getURLContent('http://carpng.com/wp-content/uploads/thumb/red-cartoon-car-8056-0.png'))

# Set height of image.
# Image has white space above and below the car
grob0 <- rasterGrob(img0, height= unit(1,"npc"), just=c("center","center"))

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy))+ geom_point()+ geom_line()
p3 <- grid.arrange(p,p,p)
grid.arrange(grob0, p3, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Cropping white space above and below the car:

```
img0 <- img0[75:225,,]
grob0 <- rasterGrob(img0, height= unit(1,"npc"), just=c("center","center"))
grid.arrange(grob0, p3, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Stretching the cropped image:

```
grob0 <- rasterGrob(img0, width=unit(1,"npc"), height=unit(1,"npc"),
         just=c("center","center"))
grid.arrange(grob0, p3, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Marco thanks for the answer. What I want is for the car to the the height of the three plots combined. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @AudileF See the modified version of my answer. Keep in mind that the image has white space around. This is why the height of the car do not reach the height of the three plots.

Comment: Thanks a mill. Works  perfect.